# Postgres and Tablespace and indexes

Tags: postgresql, indexing, tablespace

I want to ask if its possible that a situation where the main table is in a different tablespace from the index if it affects performance.
i have a senario where a large table 250GB is in a tablespace and the indexes (3) with an average size of 40GB is in default tablespace. could this be the reason why queries are slow

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Answer (score 0):

No, unless one of these tablespaces is on slow storage.

Comment: I confirm that Laurenz says and must admit that there is no problem even if the storage of indexes was much more slow than the table storage because the data are physically writes on disk asynchronously... But separates data table from indexes is an outdated form of storage needed when disk was very costly (1980/1995)...